# how to store all iterations of a for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, for-loop

So here is what I have. This is a program in which I have to take a random string, ex) "]][][sfgfbd[pdsbs]\bdgb"; and strip it of all special characters. the function "Strip" works for its purpose.

```
message=(str.lower(input("Enter a Coded message: ")))
offset=int(input("Enter Offset: "))
alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
def strip(text):
    print("Your Lower case string is: ",message)
    print("With the specials stripped: ")
    for index in text:
        if index in alphabet:
            print(index, end="")
    print()
    return strip
```

I need the output from strip in the "decode" function, but I can't seem to figure out anyway of storing the iterations of "index"

```
def decode(character):
    encrypted= ""
    for character in message:
        global offset
        if character == " ":
            encrypted+= " "
        elif ord(character) + offset > ord("z"):
            encrypted+=chr(ord(character) +offset - 26)
        else:
            encrypted+= chr(ord(character)+(offset))
    print("the decoded string is: ",encrypted,end=" ")
    print()
```

So "decode" only takes the output from the original "message" input. "Palin" however succeeds in taking decode's value.

```
def palin(code):
    print(code[::-1])
    print(code[:])
    if code[::-1]==code[:]:
        print("This is a Palindrome!")
    else:
        print("This is not a Palindrome.")
    return palin
print()
palin(decode(strip(message)))
```

Comment: Hello, sorry just to better understand what you are asking, could you possibly give an example of the output you were expecting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get confused between `print` and `return`.

You need to look carefully at the **outputs** of your methods (what they return, not what they print to the console):

- the `strip()` and `palin()` methods are returning references to themselves, rather than anything useful relating to their inputs.
- the `decode()` method isn't returning anything.

To fix this, you can use a variable inside your method, that you build based on the input variables, using the logic you want. For example:

```
def strip(text):
    print("Your Lower case string is: ",text)
    print("With the specials stripped: ")
    stripped_text = "" # <-- create and initialise a return variable
    for index in text:
        if index in alphabet:
            stripped_text += index # <-- update your return variable
            print(index, end="")
    print()
    return stripped_text # <-- return the updated variable
```

You then need to do something similar for `decode()`, although here you already have an output variable (`encrypted`) so you just need to `return` it at the end of the method.

The `palin()` method doesn't need to return anything: it just prints out the result.

---

Once you get this working, you should think about how you can use other features of the Python language to achieve your goals more easily.

For example, you can use `replace()` to simplify your `strip()` method:

```
def strip(text):
    return text.replace('[^a-z ]','') # <-- that's all you need :)
```

Comment: do I have to make stripped_text global to input it into decode?

Comment: No, `decode(strip(message))` says ‘call `decode()` using the output from `strip()`’ so whatever `strip()` returns will be used as the input for `decode()`. But for that to work, you need to fix the `decode()` method, to be `def decode(message):`

Comment: ... `def decode(character):` is wrong - the value of the `character` input is being ignored